# Regular Expression Java (punctuations)

Tags: java, regex

I would like to identify 2 types of patterns in a string. They are:

1) `xxx:xxxxxxx:xxx.xx`

2) `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxxxxxxx`

Basically I want to know how to identify a literal `"."` in a string.

Since `.` means any character,  what should I type when I am looking for a literal `"."`?

Comment: use the java Pattern  and Matcher with \\.

[source][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot

Answer (score 10):

You can either escape the `.` like this `\\.`

or

use it within character class like this `[.]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using, `String [] stringArray = string.split("\\.");` 
escaping the "."

And then `int periods = stringArray.length;`

Telling you how many periods there are in your "String"

Just a start on escaping characters. I am unsure what your question is asking so I just gave an intro to escaping.

Answer (score 0):

good luck

```
    String text    ="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxxxxxxx";

    String patternString = "(.*)(\\.)(.*)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```