# for some reason my split() works in one line of my code but not the other line

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

this line of code is messing with me,

```
String[] parseEmailDomain = parseEmail[1].split(".");
```

When i do `System.out.println(parseEmailDomain.length)` the size of the array ends up being 0 BUT the output of `System.out.println(parseEmail[1])` is

```
cs.uh.edu
```

anyone have any idea as to why when I try to split the array, it doesn't split it but when I try to just output the array it outputs perfectly fine?

I am able to do this

```
String[] parseEmail = parseLn[i].split("@");
```

the out put of `System.out.println(parseEmail[0]);` is hanak
and parseLn is an entire line from a text file

Comment: Read the javadoc of `split`.

Comment: split returns an array that would not you probably expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because `.` will match *anything* because split takes a **regex**!

you will need to escape the dot with `\`:

```
 String[] parseEmailDomain = parseEmail[1].split("\\.");
```

See also the related answer here: [Java RegEx meta character (.) and ordinary dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot)

Comment: Excellent! You may consider to accept the question then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to put two backslash's before the dot:

```
String[] parseEmailDomain = parseEmail[1].split("\\.");
```

A dot in regexes means any character.

Answer (score 1):

parameter of 'split(String)' is actually regular expression so use Scanner or StringTokenizer instead