# Regex pattern needed for 123.12/23

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check my string having `123.12/23` with pattern `\\d+(.\\d+)*\\/\\d+(.\\d+)*` but it is not working, it is passing `123.12/23/24` also.

I need below scenarios to be covered :

Strings to be passed : `12/23 , 12.23/23 , 12/23.33`

Strings to be failed : `12/13/14 , 12.23/2/4`

Comment: Do you want to pass `12.23.34/23`?

Comment: See [Java RegEx meta character (.) and ordinary dot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot)

Answer (score 3):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?\/\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

You were close.Escape the `.`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/1

For java it would be

```
^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$
```

Comment: In Java, it is enough to use `^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$`. No need escaping the forward slash.