# How to do name validation allowing alphabet, spaces and dot in android?

Tags: java, android, regex

My code cannot enter **dot**. Can someone help me?

```
public boolean isValidLastName(final String lastname){
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String LASTNAME_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z]+\\.?";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(LASTNAME_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(lasname);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: this link should be useful [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675027/5919568 ]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this one instead [a-zA-Z.\s]+ - allowing alphabet or dot or whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks it works! Ex: Adawiyah Abd. Jalil

Comment: @Adda we have very helpful resources in the internet, where you can check your expressions next time, so try for example https://regex101.com/

Comment: Nice validation - it accepts all chars except digits and `_`. What good is it?

Comment: Your regex matches lots of things, e.g. [`§§§§§@$#%^*&)(*%$#@$@#!$#$#&§`](https://regex101.com/r/ZVGgZ7/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, lol, check it.

Comment: @20fps Wiktor is correct. The `\W` already includes `.` (and everything `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`), so using `.` is useless in that regex. That pattern is the equivalent of `[^\d_]`. Your updated pattern is better.

Comment: @Makyen yes, but I corrected it already.

Comment: Thanks guys! I already change it and its works.

Answer (score 0):

Dot should be placed inside brackets.
Use this:

```
[ .a-zA-Z]+
```

You may also try \w\d in the brackets to replace , but I’m not sure if Java supports it.

Comment: Do you know lastnames that contain digits?

Comment: @Toto Oops, you’re right. Got incorrect understanding of “alphabet”

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt use double "\" like in java's String before special characters, instead just put dot in brackets.
You can always check how your regular expression works https://www.regextester.com
You can read more about regex Patterns in doc:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html